# Does a M.2 2280 SSD fit in a MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014)?

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, upgrade

I have a standard 256GB SSD right now. I would like to upgrade that to a 512GB or higher. When I was looking around I found this SAMSUNG 950 PRO 512 GB SSD that has a huge performance in write and read speed.

This SAMSUNG 950 PRO 512 GB has a M.2 2280 connection.
Is it possible to fit this inside my Macbook?

Comment: I heard the SSD is integrated to the motherboard and cannot be replaced but I'm not sure. Let's wait for answers.

Comment: Can you please tell us which Mac you have?

Comment: @IronCraftMan Me? If you mean Albert, he wrote it in the title

Comment: No without desoldering the SSD, it's integrated in the motherboard. They also use a propietary interface, not the standard M.2. A company called OWC sells replacement SSD for these kind of computers, but the replacement is not user friendly. They're not supposed to be upgradeable.

Comment: Are you sure it's solded, it doesn't look like that on this tutorial. https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+15-Inch+Retina+Display+Mid+2014+SSD+Replacement/27694 I hope that someone can give me a clear answer if the SAMSUNG 950 PRO 512 GB with the M.2 2280 connection can fit in my Macbook. My MacBook model is A1398 (MBP Retina 15 Inch mid 2014).

Comment: I doubt it's soldered, though it may be advisable to open your computer to check its form factor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can upgrade using the SSD models available from OWC.

They have the 480 GB Aura SSD and 1 TB Aura SSD which will allow you to upgrade to a larger size disk.

The actual upgrade process is quite easy. You'll have to remove the screws from the back of the laptop taking off the back. Then remote the single screw that keeps the SSD seated and mounted to the logic board, and it is easy to replace.

You can find the SSDs here:

[480 GB Aura SSD](https://eshop.macsales.com/item/OWC/SSDAB2MB05/)

[1 TB Aura SSD](https://eshop.macsales.com/item/OWC/SSDAB2MB10/)

Comment: One thing needed to mention is that the speed of these aftermarket SSD's often is way below the original one.  If you're just looking for extra storage they're a good choice, if you're looking for fast extra storage they're probably not.

Answer (score 2):

The Samsung 950pro has the same connector and the same chipset.  In fact, both the 950pro and the Samsung manufactured Apple SSD of this type share the same exact PCB and chips.  Initially the 950pro was manufactured as an OEM drive especially for Apple.

However the 950pro retail version has minor hardware differences and a complete different firmware.

While they indeed fit physically, they are NOT compatible.  There are currently no aftermarket drives for this range.  If someone would release a compatible drive in the future, the [OWC](https://www.macsales.com/) Envoy range would be my best bet.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about that particular ssd model, but if there's anything NOT soldered on the macbook pro, then that's definitely the SSD! So of course you can replace it. The crap you find on the internet from people pretending to answer IT question is unbearable.

By the way, don't be taken in completely by the specs. Not all brands perform as well as the published specs say. Intel seems to be most truthful, but it's often too expensive. If you've been able to make the change, please let me know. I'm interested in it myself.

Comment: It is not crap. It is entirely correct that a standard M.2 2280 SSD, including the Samsung model mentioned here, won't function on the Mid-2014 MacBook Pro.

Comment: @jksoegaard You've probably misread my post. I was talking about the crap written above. No one said that the m.2 connect didn't work with a mbp connector and EDP actually said exactly the opposite, that it would work. So yes, that's crap :)

Comment: You should add that as a comment to the incorrect answer, instead of adding it as a new answer - as you really provide no answer for the original question.

Comment: I couldn't add a comment back then, but that WAS an answer to his question nonetheless, i.e. m.2 ssds do not fit into a mbp. There's no issue whatsoever.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood what EDP wrote. He wrote specifically that the M.2 SSD is NOT compatible. You seem to have misread that.